# appending the div after redirect the page by window.location

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In this code i check the page name and then if i find that page, i redirect that page to the other packDetails.php and then want to append the div having the code in dataLoad(). function.
    have a look to the code :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#resultDiv').hide();
       $('#allpacks').hide();



    var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

  $('#searchButton').click(function(){              
        if(filename != 'packDetails.php')   
        {
            window.location='packDetails.php';
            window.onload = function () {
                alert('saeed');
            }();
        }
        else{
            dataLoad();
        }

    });

});
```

### dataLoad:-

```
function dataLoad()
{       
    $('#showAll').show(1500);
    $('#searchResults').html('');
    var searchValue=$('#searchb').val();
$('#searchName').html(searchValue);

if(searchValue=='')
{
    alert("Please enter a valid keyword");
}
else{

$('#searchContent').show();
$('#outerDiv').hide();
$('#result').html('');
$.ajax({
    url:'SolrResponse.php',
    data:{search: searchValue},
    success:function(responseText)
    {
        $('#resultDiv').show();
        $('#allpacks').hide();

        var data= responseText.substring(0, responseText.length - 1);

        var object= JSON.parse(data);
        var response= object.response;                      
        var div=$('<div></div>');
        var docs= response.docs;
        resultData=docs;
        var length= docs.length;


        if(length>0)
        {
            for(var i=0; i<length; i++)
            {

                var mainDiv=$('<div id="mainDiv"></div>');
                var packName=$('<div id="namePack">'+docs[i].packName+'</div>');
                var packDesc=$('<div id="descPack">'+docs[i].packDescription+'</div>');

                var packVer=$('<div id="verPack">Pack Version: '+docs[i].packVersion+'</div>');
                var packAuth=$('<div id="authPack">Author: '+docs[i].packAuthor+'</div>');

                var entityN= docs[i].entityName;
                var entityD= docs[i].entityDescription;
                var entityT=docs[i].entityType;

                var entityDet=$('<div id="entityDet"></div>');
                for(var j=0;j<entityN.length;j++)
                {

                    if((entityN[j].toUpperCase()).indexOf(searchValue.toUpperCase()) > -1)
                    {
                        entityN[j]=entityN[j].replace(searchValue, '<span>'+searchValue+'</span>');
                        var entityName=$('<div id="nameEn">'+entityN[j]+' ('+entityT[j]+')</div>');
                        entityDet.append(entityName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if((entityD[j].toUpperCase()).indexOf(searchValue.toUpperCase()) > -1)
                        {
                            entityD[j]=entityD[j].replace(searchValue, '<span>'+searchValue+'</span>');
                            var entityName=$('<div id="nameEn">'+entityD[j]+' ('+entityT[j]+')</div>');
                            entityDet.append(entityName);
                        }

                    }


                }

                mainDiv.append(packName);
                mainDiv.append(packDesc);
                mainDiv.append(packVer);
                mainDiv.append(packAuth);
                mainDiv.append(entityDet);

                $('#searchResults').append(mainDiv);                                

            }

        }


    else
            {
                $('#searchResults').html("No Data Found");
            }

          }
        });
      }
}
```

Comment: So you want your current's page code to execute within the scope of the new page once it has been loaded by changing `window.location`? Is that your question?

Comment: yes i need to append the div after redirect to the other page my search is global and need when from any page i search it will go to the search page and my ajax content will load on the div on that search page ..

Comment: You cannot do this that way since once the location has changed, the current execution environment gets unloaded. Your code will have to run from that newly loaded page. If you need to pass data to that page, there are multiple mechanism that can be used. You can pass GET params through the URL or submit a form to that page instead of simply changing `window.location`. You could also use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/Storage) or session variables on the server.